# How to realize UIPickerView with RXSwift

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, rx-swift

#### just like UITableView

```
    items.bindTo(tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "cellIdentifier", cellType: AttentionTableViewCell.self)){(row,dic,cell) in
        cell.configueCell(with: dic)
    }.addDisposableTo(dispose)
```

Comment: Can you please add what you have tried and what you want as the result ?

Comment: http://oikehvl7k.bkt.clouddn.com/UIPickerView.png

Comment: I suggest you to improve question by giving more details...rather than sharing using comment.

Answer (score 11):

Maybe you just have to update your RxSwift library version. It looks like pretty much the same as UI{Table|Collection}View rx bindings.
Supposing you have a data source like:

```
let items: Observable<[String]> = Observable.of(["Row1", "Row2", "Row3"])
```

To populate your UIPickerView:

```
items.bind(to: yourPickerView.rx.itemTitles) { (row, element) in
    return element
}
.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

To handle selected items:

```
yourPickerView.rx.itemSelected
    .subscribe { (event) in
        switch event {
        case .next(let selected):
            print("You selected #\(selected.row)")
        default:
            break
        }
    }
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 9):

Swift4 example

```
Observable.just(["Yes", "No", "Maybe"])
                .bind(to: picker.rx.itemTitles) { _, item in
                    return "\(item)"
                }
                .disposed(by: disposeBag)



picker.rx.itemSelected
                .subscribe(onNext: { (row, value) in
                    NSLog("selected: \(row)")
                })
                .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@IBOutlet weak var pickerView: UIPickerView!
let disposeBag = DisposeBag()
```

Binding an array from 1 to 12 to the pickerview.

```
Observable.of(Array(1...12)).bind(to: pickerView.rx.itemTitles) { (row, element) in
    return String(element)
}.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Binding the selected value to anyLabel. You can bind it accordingly.

```
pickerView.rx.itemSelected.asObservable().map { value in String(value.row + 1) }.bind(to: anyLabel.rx.text).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided data source of your picker looks like this:

```
let pickerDataSource: [[String]] = [ ["asdadadad", "sffgddfg"],
                                     ["sfsdasgag", "sdfasdfasfsf", "sdsfgagagaggs"] ]
```

you could implement 'binding' in this way:

```
pickerView.rx.itemSelected.subscribe(onNext: {[weak self](row,component) in
    guard let s = self else { return }
    s.label.text = s.pickerDataSource[component][row]
}).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```