# RxSwift and UIPickerView

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, rx-swift, rx-cocoa

Is there a way to bind a `UIPickerView` with an Observable?

For example for a `UITableView` I would do:

```
myObservableArray.bindTo(tableView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "Identifier", cellType: MyCustomTableViewCell.self)) { (row, title, cell) in
        cell.textLabel?.text = title
    }
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Is there something similar for `UIPickerView` ?

Comment: There is nothing usable out of the box from RxSwift's repository. One could look at the code used for `UITableView` bindings to come up with something similar for `UIPickerView`, but you'd need a pretty good experience with RxSwift to get a grasp of how that works (at least, **I** tried and failed)

Comment: Please take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46225009/1953178

Answer (score 2):

As a matter of fact there is, in the RxCocoa library:

Example:

```
let items = Observable.just([
        "First Item",
        "Second Item",
        "Third Item"
    ])

items
    .bind(to: pickerView.rx.itemTitles) { (row, element) in
        return element
    }
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

There's also:

```
items
   .bind(to: pickerView.rx.items) { (row, element, view) in
       guard let myView = view as? MyView else {
           let view = MyView()
           view.configure(with: element)
           return view
       }
       myView.configure(with: element)
       return myView
   }
   .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: How to do this for `UIDatePicker` in `RxSwift` ? Any tutorial ?

Comment: The date picker class already has a reactive extension. Look at `rx.date`.

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/blob/master/RxCocoa/iOS/UIDatePicker%2BRx.swift , I have read this link. I don't know how to get chosen date from `UIDatePicker`. Can u guide me?

Comment: I have mailed u regarding this doubt. datePicker.rx.date
            .subscribe { (datee) in
                
                print("chosen date     ", datee)
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag) . Is this right way to get chose date from `UIDatePickerView` ?

Comment: That's not appropriate. If you have a question about something. Ask it on this site or in the RxSwift slack channel. Someone will answer it (maybe even me.)

Comment: Hi Daniel. In the first example, 'element.title' doesn't seem right. Element is just a string here, isn't it?

Comment: Good catch @Dale I fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Provided data source of your picker looks like this:

```
let pickerDataSource: [[String]] = [ ["asdadadad", "sffgddfg"],
                                     ["sfsdasgag", "sdfasdfasfsf", "sdsfgagagaggs"] ]
```

you could implement 'binding' you need in this way:

```
pickerView.rx.itemSelected.subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] row, component in
    guard let s = self else { return }
    s.label.text = s.pickerDataSource[component][row]
}).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Comment: Getting the item is fine with `itemSelected`, but how do you bind the 2D array to the pickerView?